# Type mismatch compile error for JDK 8 source in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm attempting to compile the Java 1.8.0_45 source (java.** packages only) using the same JDK as compiler in Eclipse Luna, and get the below compile error for line 1599 of MethodHandleImpl.java:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<? extends Object[]> to Class<? extends Object[]>`

The offending line is:

`Class<? extends Object[]> objArrayType = arrayType.asSubclass(Object[].class);`

Interestingly, compiling the same source from the command line produces no errors when I use:

`javac -sourcepath ./java -cp rt.jar @classes`

where 'classes' contains the list of classes to compile, including java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl.java

I'd like to know why eclipse flags this as an error? Looking at the type mismatch eclipse errors with, the 'from' and 'to' types are the same!

Comment: Check if you have source compatiblity on your project set to pre-8

Comment: Both compiler compliance level and source compatibility set to 1.8.

Comment: Eclipse uses its own compiler. It sometimes has different behavior.

Comment: I had the same issue as eclipse kept trying to use the JRE instead of the JDK.  Once I added the JDK to eclipse and selected it instead of the JRE, this went away.

Comment: @JohnSnyder I have only one entry in the installed JREs, and that points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home` which is just above the JDK (`/bin/javac` etc are immediately below) so as far as I can tell I'm using a full JDK here?  MacOS 10.10.3 BTW in case that's relevant...

Comment: As a side note, that’s not even Java 8 specific code. That should work since Java **5** and it does, even with Eclipse Luna, without Java 8 compliance. Well, my Luna does compile that construct (tested in isolation, I did not try to compile the JRE). So if there is such a bug, it must have been introduced in a very specific minor version.

Comment: Have you removed the JDK itself from the project's build classpath? If you are trying to compile the JDK itself, the Eclipse compiler might well have the JDK's `java.lang.Object` on one side, and the one it is currently compiling on the other side, hence the conversion issue (similarly to when you have a `ClassCastException` for the same class loaded by 2 different class loaders).

Comment: @DidierL interesting suggestion, but the problem is because I'm only trying to compile the `java` package I depend on rt.jar and jce.jar to be able to compile.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: I never actually tried to compile the JDK so I don't know if the java package depends on other packages, but if it is the case I guess you cannot compile it alone.

Comment: I edited rt.jar to delete `java.lang.Object` from it, but I still get the same compile error.